# MySQL incorrect nested query output when use table name

Tags: mysql

I have encountered a very odd situation with MySQL (replicated with same results in PSQL) when a query return the right result when is used a table name alias but wrong result when is used full table name.

Please see bellow for full details:

We have the following 2 table COURSE and STUDENT
COURSE table has 2 records
STUDENT table have 12 records
(*I left out the FKs and any other attribute for example replication*)

[A live sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3wmdSL1uZP8pMU9ENRhBSb/1) or code below

```
-- Table structure for course
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `course`;
CREATE TABLE `course`  (
  `courseNo` int NOT NULL,
  `courseTitle` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseNo`)
);

-- Records of course
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES (1000, 'Software Engineering');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES (1001, 'Internet Systems');

-- Table structure for student
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student`  (
  `studentid` int NOT NULL,
  `courseNo` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
);

-- Records of student
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3000, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3001, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3002, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3003, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3004, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3005, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3006, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3007, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3008, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3009, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3010, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3011, 1001);
```

If I run the following nested query

```
SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
       COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
FROM course c,
     student s
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student
         WHERE s.courseNo = c.courseNo )
GROUP BY c.courseNo;
```

The result is correct 5 students are enrolled in course 1000, and 7 in course 1001.

| Course ID | Course Title | Enrolled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Software Engineering | 5 |
| 1001 | Internet Systems | 7 |

However if I run the following nested query

```
Select course.courseNo as 'Course ID',
       course.courseTitle as 'Course Title',
       COUNT(student.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
From course,
     student
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student
         WHERE student.courseNo = course.courseNo )
Group by course.courseNo;
```

The result is

| Course ID | Course Title | Enrolled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Software Engineering | 12 |
| 1001 | Internet Systems | 12 |

They are exactly the same queries. The only difference is the alias in the table names.
If I do as a normal JOIN both versions are returning the correct result.

If anyone can explain this behavior of the nested query will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not the same queries, not the same result.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They are absolutely *not* the same query.

The first one refers only to the outer tables in its inner `WHERE`, but the second has a correlation instead

---

### In the first query:

```
FROM course c,
     student s
```

This is a cross-join of both tables. Generally you should avoid this syntax, and favour explicit join syntax, this is really the root cause of your problems.

---

```
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
```

There must be at least one row from the subquery. Note that `SELECT *` is the same as `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL` here.

---

```
         FROM student
         WHERE s.courseNo = c.courseNo )
```

The `WHERE` only refers to the outer tables. And once you use explicit join syntax,  it's effectively the same as

```
FROM course c
JOIN student s ON s.courseNo = c.courseNo
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
         FROM student)
```

The `EXISTS` just checks that *at least one row* exists anywhere in the `student` table, which is normally true anyway. It is unnecessary for your results, you can drop the whole `WHERE`

---

### In the second query:

```
From course,
     student
```

Again you use old-style comma joins, when you shouldn't, and you have no alias

---

```
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student
         WHERE student.courseNo = course.courseNo )
```

Here the inner `student` table also has no alias. So when you write `WHERE student.courseNo = course.courseNo` you are correlating the inner `student` to the outer `course` table.

But the outer comma cross-join remains in place, and has no correlation. So you are cross-joining everything together, then ensuring that each `course` has at least one student. This is simply bogus.

---

### Your query should really be this

```sql
SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
       COUNT(*) AS 'Enrolled'  -- COUNT(notNullValue) is the same as COUNT(*)
FROM course c
JOIN student s ON s.courseNo = c.courseNo
GROUP BY
    c.courseNo,
    c.courseTitle;  -- always group by all non-aggregated columns
```

Alternatively

```sql
SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
       s.Enrolled
FROM course c
JOIN (
    SELECT s.courseNo,
           COUNT(*) AS 'Enrolled'  -- COUNT(notNullValue) is the same as COUNT(*)    
    FROM student s
    GROUP BY
        s.courseNo
) s ON s.courseNo = c.courseNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second one, student.courseNo uses the column from the table in the subselect. You shouldn't use the subselect in none of the queries.